# Click() Function Not Working HtmlUnit

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

Hey I'm having some trouble clicking a button to submit a comment on a thread using htmlUnit. I get the element by using this

```
HtmlPage newOne = webClient.getPage(string);
//System.out.println(newOne.asText());
HtmlTextArea area = (HtmlTextArea) newOne.getElementById("ctrl_message_html");
area.focus();
area.type('t');

newOne.getHtmlElementByAccessKey('s').click();
```

Which throws

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: 404 Not Found for http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/plugin-idea-to-get-tons-of-downloads.271185/members/jthort.90885864/post
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.throwFailingHttpStatusCodeExceptionIfNecessary(WebClient.java:514)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadDownloadedResponses(WebClient.java:2067)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:717)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.processPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:804)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1322)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1265)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1213)
at HTMLUnit.main(HTMLUnit.java:87)
```

When I print out the element, I get this

```
HtmlSubmitInput[<input type="submit" class="button primary MenuCloser" value="Post" accesskey="s">]
```

But I don't understand why it would be throwing an exception when it clearly has the right object. I have javascript disabled, along with css. I am using the web browser Chrome.

Edit: By right Object I mean that it's the correct button on the page that I want to click and it's in the form of a HtmlSubmitInput button.

Comment: Any reason this is tagged javascript and not java?

Comment: My mistake I chose the wrong tag, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think having *the right object* will mean you won't get any exception. You're not getting a `NullPointerException`, if that is what you mean by *the right object*.

Having said that, if you read the exception it is a `FailingHttpStatusCodeException` with the following message:

> 404 Not Found for http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/plugin-idea-to-get-tons-of-downloads.271185/members/jthort.90885864/post

So that URL is giving you a 404 error when you perform an HTTP POST on it. You should keep debugging why this is happening. I would enable JavaScript, maybe it is needed there.

Comment: By right object I simply meant that I was clicking the button I wanted to click. I've tried enabling JavaScript and it doesn't seem to help. I have tried multiple methods to work around this problem and nothing seems to work. There aren't any work arounds that I know of that can submit this forum without the use of that button. How would I find out more specifically the cause of this?